# Adding duplicate code in common file cypress

Tags: testing, automation, cucumber, cypress

Sorry it this is an obvious question, I just cant seem to figure it out.

I am using cypress and cucumber to create my tests. My file structure looks like this

[image]

What I am wanting to do is add steps in the `assertionStepDifinition.js` file that can be used in my `login.feature` and my `register.feature`

This is my `cypress.json`

```
{

  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "failOnStatusCode": false,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 60000,
  "testFiles": "**/*.feature"

}
```

Currently I am getting the error  `Step implementation missing for: I am at the login page`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most probably you need to add to your `package.json`

```
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "step_definitions": "cypress/integration/**/"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the direct path from where the step definition file is located in your `package.json` like this:

```js
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration/cucumber-test/"
  }
```

Comment: I added this with the right path, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Updated the answer. How about you add it till the `common` folder.

Comment: Thats how I did it the first time.

Comment: Have you tried without common? just this `cypress/integration/cucumber-test/`

Comment: Yeah same outcome

Comment: @ItsNotAndy As correctly pointed out by @Zhenëk, the file should be `package.json` and not `cypress.json`.